# Remove 'x' Input Decoration In Microsoft Edge (formerly Project Spartan)

Tags: css, internet-explorer-11, windows-10, microsoft-edge

In the CSS of a website I'm currently working on we use the following CSS to hide the 'x' button that Internet Explorer 10 and 11 add to input fields for users to clear their contents:

```
input::-ms-clear {
  display: none;
}
```

Viewing the same website in the first build of Microsoft Edge (formerly codenamed "Project Spartan") on Windows 10 Build 10049 this CSS has no effect. This isn't surprising as Microsoft Edge is breaking away from the legacy of Internet Explorer, but I want to achieve the same effect.

What is the equivalent CSS required for Microsoft Edge to not render this?

Comment: I guess this makes you the first person to ask a question about Spartan :)

Comment: Cannot reproduce on my build - it works just fine for me. `::-ms-clear` has nothing to do with IE legacy. It is a new, non-standard feature introduced in Windows 8 and IE10.

Comment: Well, what I meant more was that anything IE-specific/non-standards would likely work differently in Project Spartan. My understanding that Project Spartan is trying to shed the legacy of Internal Explorer and its perception, hence different User Agent, name, standards-only etc.

Comment: I would say that `::-ms-clear` isn't so much IE-specific as it is Windows-specific. Project Spartan still has to implement it by virtue of being a part of Windows, since Windows will have to make use of EdgeHTML to render HTML/CSS-based Windows apps. Anyway, do you have a reproducible test case?

Comment: I'll re-test this myself later today once I've got access to the machine with a Windows 10 VM on it and re-try what I was doing when I found this initially.

Comment: Project Spartan hasn't been released yet, so this question is premature. On that note, have you tried just `input {}`?

Comment: @TylerH - the trouble with `input { display: none; }` is that while the crosses would be gone, so would every `input` element ;)

Comment: In Webkit you would use:

input[type=search]::-webkit-search-decoration,
input[type=search]::-webkit-search-cancel-button {
    -webkit-appearance:none;
}

I very much doubt the vendor specific selectors follow each other but ::-ms-search-decoration might exist?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It turns out that the CSS had been broken since it was originally written, and this wasn't working in IE 10+ either.

Since fixing the CSS, Microsoft Edge (formerly Project Spartan) is behaving the same as IE10+ and not displaying the 'x' in input fields.

Comment: I could not get it. `::-ms-clear { display:none; }` was not working for IE10? If not, what selector have you used?

Comment: We have something like this in a LESS file we compile our CSS from: ```.my-class { input { &::-ms-clear { display: none; } } }```

Answer (score 2):

Also you can use `type="text"` in input field to remove that **X**

Comment: As far as I can tell, in Edge 42.17134.1.0, adding or removing `type="text"` has no effect. `::-ms-clear{display:none;}` does work though.

Comment: I'm using a input type text and still appearing the X